# Array-Based List - Insert Function

Tags: c++, arraylist

I have implemented the following insert function in my code along with a find function,

```
template <class Elem>
bool AList<Elem>::insert(const Elem& item) 
{
    if (listSize == maxSize) return false;

    for (int i = listSize; i > fence; i--)
    {
        listArray[i] = listArray[i - 1];
    }

    listArray[fence + 1] = item;
    listSize++; 
    return true;
}
bool find(const Elem& item) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
        if (listArray[i].getCode() == item.getCode()) 
            return true;
  return false;       
}
void print()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < listSize; i++)
        listArray[i].print();
}
void insertMajor(AList<Major> &t, Major &m)
{
    if (t.find(m))
       cout << "The major already exists!" << endl;
    else
       t.insert(m); //inserting major
}
```

I have then created 3 objects of a class major, and made a list of those majors, however when I "cout" the list, M1 is missing.

```
AList<Major> list(5);
Major M1("ECE", "Electrical Engineering");
Major M2("CCE", "Computer Engineering");
Major M3("MATH", "Mathematics");

insertMajor(list, M1);
insertMajor(list, M2);
insertMajor(list, M3);

cout << "The list contains " << list.getSize() << " majors." << endl;
cout << "--------------- \n";
list.print();
cout << "--------------- \n";
```

Output:

```
The list contains 3 majors.
--------------- 

Major Code: MATH
Major Description: Mathematics
Major Code: CCE
Major Description: Computer Engineering
---------------
```

I tried finding out why it seems to swallow the first element in the list, but I can't seem to figure it out. Could anyone enlighten me?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `print`, you have to use:

```
void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        listArray[i].print();
}
```

or

```
void print()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= listSize; i++)
        listArray[i].print();
}
```

Otherwise, you are going to miss an element.

Since you indicated that the first element is not used. It is used as a "fence", you will need to use:

```
void print()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= listSize; i++)
        listArray[i].print();
}
```

but then, you'll need to change:

```
for (int i = listSize; i > fence; i--)
{
    listArray[i] = listArray[i - 1];
}
```

in `insert` to

```
for (int i = listSize; i > fence; i--)
{
    listArray[i+1] = listArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you help me implement the remove function as well? Here is what I wrote but since you had me change insert, I should change remove as well: `bool remove(Elem &it)
 {
  if (rightLength() == 0) return false;

  it = listArray[fence]; 

  for (int i = fence; i < listSize - 1; i++)
  {
   listArray[i] = listArray[i + 1]; 
  }

  listSize--;
  return true;
 }`

Comment: @kevin001, it will be better to create another post, with an MCVE, to address that question.

Comment: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey man, I posted my question to remove function, no one seems to have come up with an answer. Could you help me figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You print function starts at index 1 of your list.

I am pretty sure you meant **`for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)`**

```
void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        listArray[i].print();
}
```

Comment: Hey coincoin, I have chosen and have been taught to keep the first element of the list empty so that with the fence method, I am able to insert an element at the head, else it would be impossible to do! When I do put the index to 0, I get empty strings for description and code!

Comment: As said in R Sahu's answer you should maybe print listArray[listSize] since you use your index 0 is reserved.